# Cannot get NGen with ASP.NET working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ngen

I'm trying to use NGEN with an ASP.NET application to improve start up time. (I appreciate this isn't an ideal solution but I'm being asked to look into it)

I can run nGEN against my target DLL and am now getting the message "All compilation targets are up to date".

However, when I try to verify whether this is working by starting the application and using the Assembly Binding Log Viewer (ticking Native Images in the log categories) , I don't see any my application listed, which suggests that it isn't working for some reason.

I feel sure I'm missing something obvious, anyone know of a way I can verify whether the NGEN images are being used?

Comment: Are you missing the dynamic compilation of views, etc in ASP.NET (hence DLLs created in temp ASP.NET folders)?

Comment: I'm not precompiling Views if that's what you mean?

Comment: We do not. ASP.NET does it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx

Comment: You've lost me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx).

If you **pre-compile** the ASP.NET app and then NGEN, you can achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: So, do I need to pre-compile the ASP.NET application before leveraging any benefit from NGEN?

Comment: Well, this is where the full benefit comes.

Comment: But can I get some benefit without pre-compile?

Comment: If it is compiled once accessed first, how can you NGEN it? It is not even compiled yet then.